# How can I display a snapshot of my widget in the App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

How can I show in my app a snapshot of a widget?
I created an app where you can modify the widget (like colors, text...). I would like to show in real time a preview of the widget. How can I do?

Comment: The code that renders the widget is all SwiftUI -- you can use the same code in your app to render a "snapshot" of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Select Widget views target membership same as app.

You can use Widgets code in your app.

[image]